# JQuery event causes script to fail

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch

I have a script which runs fine when it is fired by `$(document).ready(function(){` however if fired by  `$("#go").click(function(event){` it fails. `#go` is the ID of a button on the page.

What I want is when I click the button to pass in form variables to my Elastic Search query and present the results back.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#go").click(function(event){
    var data = 
    { "query":{"filtered":{ "query":{"match_all":{}}, "filter":{"and":[{"script":{"script":"true"}}]} }}, "fields":["_id", "_title"], "from":0, "size":10, "sort":[]};
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9200/_search',
            type: 'POST',
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(response) {
           alert("success!");
                   var data = response.hits.hits;
                    var doc_ids = [];
                    var source = null;
                    var content = '';

                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            source = data[i].fields;
                            doc_ids.push(source._id);
                            content = content + ' ' + source._id + '<br />';
                        }

                        $('#results').html(content);
                    } else {
                        $('#results').html('No results found.');
                    }

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    alert("fail!");

                    var jso = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                    error_note('section', 'error', '(' + jqXHR.status + ') ' + errorThrown + ' --<br />' + jso.error);
                }
            });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using `crossDomain: true`? and by *"it fails"* do you mean you get the fail alert?

Comment: Yes, my 'fail!' alert fires when I put this inside the #go button click. I copied this from another page that had the crossDomain: true. Would it help if I dropped that?

Comment: Well, It's purpose is to emulate a cross-domain reqeust when doing a same-domain request, it's very rare to need it.

Comment: Why are you using POST for a query?

Comment: You should probably use JSONP to avoid having problems with cross domain. Elasticsearch support it out of the box. `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search?callback=myCalbbackName -d '{"query": {"match_all":{}}}'`